# Can't call public method while looping over object array

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to play around a bit with OOP in JavaScript and I have an array of simple objects that I'm trying to loop over and call a method on each, however, when I run this under Google Chrome, I get the following exception in the JavaScript debugger:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'drawHisto'
```

Simplified code snippet below:

```js
var histograms = [];
var h1 = null;
var h2 = null;
var h3 = null;

function Init() {
    h1 = new Histogram(canvas1, "red");
    h2 = new Histogram(canvas2, "blue");
    h3 = new Histogram(canvas3, "green");

    histograms = [ h1, h2, h3];
}

function Histogram(canvas, color) {
    // this is my constructor
}

Histogram.prototype.drawHisto = function() {
    // I will add code here to draw the histogram
}

function DrawHistograms() {
    for (var h in histograms) {
        h.drawHisto(); // Throws exception!
    }

    // h1.drawHisto() <--- this works
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I've simplified the code here a bit, so if you find that the problem must be elsewhere, I can add additional context.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for in` loop in JavaScript does not iterate over an array's values, but rather over an object's keys. Simply use a `for` loop as usual:

```
function DrawHistograms() {
    for (var i = 0; i < histograms.length; i++) {
        histograms[i].drawHisto();
    }
}
```

Or, if compatibility with Internet Explorer 8 and earlier is no issue, you may be able to use `Array.forEach`:

```
function DrawHistograms() {
    histograms.forEach(function(h) {
        h.drawHisto();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var h in histograms) {
    histograms[h].drawHisto();
}
```

The for-in-loop in Javascript can be surprising at first: it doesn't loop over the *values* of the array, but rather the *keys*. For a straight-up array, I tend to prefer the more verbose but clearer standard for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < histograms.length; i++) {
    histograms[i].drawHisto();
}
```

Fun fact time! The for-in-loop can be handy for iterating over key-value mappings like `{foo: 'bar', spam: 'eggs'}`, but beware: it'll iterate over inherited keys, as well. For example, if some wiseguy decided to declare `Object.prototype.myMethod`, you'd see the keys `foo`, `spam`, and `myMethod` appear. The `hasOwnProperty` method can make the loop safe, though:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         // proceed with confidence
    }
}
```